# WordPress RSS Feeds Slow Queries: How to fix/prevent

Tags: wordpress, performance, rss

Our main website is running WordPress 6.0.3 on PHP 8.0 with a MariaDB 10.x database.

We are using New Relic (NR) for system and application metrics and are noticing a particular SQL query consistently showing in the NR "Slow SQL traces" table.  Upon narrowing it down further, these slow queries are coming from the WP RSS Feeds.

Some examples:

- https://www.example.org/search/results/feed/rss
- https://www.example.org/search/results/feed/rss2
- https://www.example.org/category/tech-news-post/feed

We can pretty much hit any RSS feed URL and within about 10 to 30 seconds it'll show up in the NR "Slow SQL traces" table.

The Query looks like this behemoth:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ?=? AND 
(((wp_posts.post_title LIKE ?) OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE ?) OR 
(wp_posts.post_content LIKE ?))) AND (wp_posts.post_password = ?) AND 
((wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?)) OR 
(wp_posts.post_type = ? AND (wp_posts.post_status = ? OR wp_posts.post_status = ?))) 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE ? DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

**Any idea how to optimize this RSS query, or perhaps cache it?**

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Indexing Database Table fields:

```
wp_posts:
post_title, post_excerpt, post_content, post_password, post_type and post_date etc.
```

used in query.
Follow Step: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

**Update on this item**:

We found that many of the "wp_posts.post_type = ?" statements in the query I mentioned are related to our WP Custom Post Types.  (Six of those statements were in regard to our custom types.)

Since they shouldn't be queried in our case, I have removed them from the *get_posts()* flow via the fields:

```
    'exclude_from_search'   => true,
    'publicly_queryable'    => false,
```

in the *register_post_type()* config.  (No core WP logic was altered, just our custom post registration settings.)

After this, the RSS query stopped showing in our NR "Slow SQL traces" table.